# Bootstrap4: extended table with multi value

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2, bootstrap-table

It is possible to create a Bootstrap extended table that looks like this (Select witch multi values from the searching table):

[image: exmample]

If, for example, the following libraries were used:

1. https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table
2. https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/4.0.3.html